# How do you say $3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3$?

Tags: notation

How do you say $3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3$? English is my second language and I'm not sure how I should read it.

Comment: What does it mean? Where did you find it?

Comment: Maybe you mean $3^{3^{3^3}}$ If so you could use the term "to the power" or "exponent"

Comment: Also related is this:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation

Comment: Three [pentated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentation) with itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase literally means "$a$ triple uparrow $a$".

Mathematically this is Knuths up-arrow notation. In a simpler case, $a \uparrow \uparrow a$ means $a$ exponentiated $a$ times. $$\underbrace{a^{{a}^{{a}^{{\cdot}^{{\cdot}^{{\cdot}^{a}}}}}}}_{\text{#} a \text{ times}}$$

This is also called teration.

In your case, $a \uparrow \uparrow \uparrow a$ is the iteration of tetration, which is $a \uparrow \uparrow(a \uparrow \uparrow a)$ or

$$\underbrace{{\left(\underbrace{a^{a^{{\cdot}^{\cdot^{a^{}}}}}}_{\text{#} a\text{ times}}\right)^{{\left(\underbrace{a^{a^{{\cdot}^{\cdot^{a}}}}}_{\text{#} a\text{ times}}\right)}^{{\left(\underbrace{a^{a^{{\cdot}^{\cdot^{a^{}}}}}}_{\text{#} a\text{ times}}\right)}^{{\cdot}^{{\cdot}^{\cdot^{{\cdot}^{{\cdot}^{\left(\underbrace{a^{a^{{\cdot}^{\cdot^{a^{}}}}}}_{\text{#} a\text{ times}}\right)}}}}}}}}}}_{\text{#} a \text{ times}}$$

Answer (score 2):

It should be read "3 three (or triple) arrow 3".

[Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GuigptwlVHo) at 2:35